# IdentityServer4 Quickstart issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I am currently at this page of the IdentityServer 4 guide http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html and I am trying to start the MVC application.

However, I keep getting this error when I start my Client application

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.Services.IIdentityServerInteractionService' while attempting to activate 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.HomeController'.
```

I went into the IdentityServer4 GitHub and copied the code from there but it doesn't run at all.

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

This is my Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace IdentityServerClient
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
I can't get to the login page shown on the documentation as well.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using the quickstart UI, you should be using the guide on it, here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI

To quote that page:

> Next you need to configure the authentication handlers:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // some details omitted
        services.AddIdentityServer();

        services.AddAuthentication()
        ...
```

You're missing:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryCaching()
    .AddClientStore<InMemoryClientStore>()
    .AddResourceStore<InMemoryResourcesStore>(); // <-- Add this
```

As a result, none of the identity server services are registered to the dependency injection container, which is why you're seeing that error.

Looks like the tutorial documentation you linked to is out of date.

--

Here is a complete set of steps to follow:

- dotnet new sln -n HelloID4
- dotnet new mvc -n HelloID4
- dotnet sln add HelloID4/HelloID4.csproj
- cd HelloID4
- git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI
- cp -r IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/* .
- dotnet add package IdentityServer4
- rm -r Controllers/
- dotnet watch run

Now modify your `Startup.cs` to look like this:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    }); services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryCaching()
        .AddClientStore<InMemoryClientStore>()
        .AddResourceStore<InMemoryResourcesStore>();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying! I tried that but it just gives me this error: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.Stores.IClientStore' while attempting to activate 'IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator'.

Comment: Also, if I follow the link you gave me, it asks me to add app.useidentityserver(). That will result in this error: 'No storage mechanism for clients specified. Use the 'AddInMemoryClients' extension method to register a development version

Also, the link you provided doesn't show what to put in Program and Startup.cs

Comment: @JianYA Not sure then I'm afraid; all I can say is I followed the instructions on github, and ignored the docs on identityserver.io and it worked for me?

Comment: Can I see your Program.cs and Startup.cs? Maybe I have to follow yours

Comment: Also, Is the Quickstart file the controller? Or is it just a folder called Quickstart

Comment: Yes. The quickstart folder contains all the controllers; you have to delete the scaffold controllers to use it correctly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I've managed to get the page to load. But it looks like the basic one. It doesn;t have a login function. Is this the correct version? I've added a screenshot to my question to take a look.

Comment: Am I supposed to run the console before running the mvc client?

Comment: @JianYA I think perhaps you should look at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples; the sample you're looking at is probably not what you want. Have a look at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Clients/src/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L83 ; there are many fully working samples in that repository to learn from.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look from there. But just to clarify. Will the startup you provide work in all cases?

Comment: No. The in memory store is only for trivial local testing. You should use real stores for production load balanced deployments. --> http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html

Comment: docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html is a dead link

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*

*Review this code : it may help, because i am also learning on it, and its working for me. *

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                //.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnectionString"), sql =>
                            sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })

                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnectionString"),
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                });
                //.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                //.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())


            services.AddAuthentication();

        }


    // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        // client credentials client
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
            },

            // resource owner password grant client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ro.client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
            },

            // OpenID Connect hybrid flow and client credentials client (MVC)


        };
    }
```

**if you are not using in-memory service**

If you are getting this error : Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.Stores.IClientStore'

Register the stores and implementation explicitly  : ( give a try )

```
    services.AddScoped<IUserStore<User>, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<IClientStore, ClientService>();
    services.AddScoped<IScopeStore, ScopeService>();
    services.AddScoped<IPersistedGrantStore, GrantService>();
```

Comment: Hi, it says I must generate multiple classes. Where do those classes go to?

Comment: are you using in memory stores ?  show us yr auth' start up

Comment: My startup is posted in my question. And yes I am using in memory stores.

Comment: I added my auth's startup code, review that, it may help.